# Add Tweetinvi to mono without nuget

Tags: linux, mono, nuget, monodevelop, tweetinvi

I had to make a .NET project in Linux using monodevelop. When I tried monodevelop in Ubuntu I got an error message when I used nuget at certain packages saying my version is 2.8 and I needed 2.12 or earlier.I updated nuget package successfully in terminal but monodevelop uses 2.8 no matter what I do. The nuget package I can't use because of this is Tweetinvi.

In order to solve this I have to either add tweetinvi without using nuget or manage to use nuget 2.12 running from outside monodevelop, which I could not find out how to do.

https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop does not use the NuGet version supplied by Mono that is available from the command line. So updating the command line version of NuGet will not resolve any problems with MonoDevelop.

More recent versions of MonoDevelop use later versions of NuGet.

The last MonoDevelop version 5 release was version 5.10 which supports NuGet 2.8.7.

Support for MonoDevelop 2.12 was added in MonoDevelop 6.0.2. NuGet v3 support was added in MonoDevelop 6.1. Currently MonoDevelop 6 is only available as a [FlatPak package](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/) unless you build it from source.

If you cannot build MonoDevelop from source you may be able to upgrade NuGet by copying the NuGet.Core.dll from [the mono/nuget-binary GitHub repository](https://github.com/mono/nuget-binary/tree/2.12) and copying it into the NuGet addin directory `addins/MonoDevelop.PackageManagement`, but take a backup copy of the original NuGet.Core.dll before you do that so you can rollback the change if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of the library and the installation of the library without nuget is not supported on mono because I do not have enough time to look into it.

Tweetinvi supports mono > 4.5 with nuget.